# How to make all circles in this example have the same radii?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The nodes with less than 4 digits appear smaller.  I'd like to have them all of the same size and I can't seem to understand enough of the documentation to get it right.  Feel free to suggest me a better way to do this.  I'd love to be able to define a function $f(x) = x^2 + 8 \mod 3127$ with $x_0 = 2$ which is where these numbers come from.

[image: A cycle of polynomial numbers]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {11}
\def \radius {3.5cm}
\def \margin {10}

\def \s {1}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$456$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {2}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$1562$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {3}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$792$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {4}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$1872$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {5}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$2152$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {6}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$25$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {7}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$441$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {8}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$615$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {9}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$2993$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {10}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$2329$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {11}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$2031$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you want is to control the node size.

Comment: Your modulus function should produce labels as shown in my last edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wish is to control the node size. So, you can use `minimum width`. For example:

[image]

In this case, you don't need to write `[draw, circle]` all the time.

(Also, consider using `foreach`.)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=1.2cm}]

\def \n {11}
\def \radius {3.5cm}
\def \margin {10}

\def \s {1}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$456$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {2}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$1562$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {3}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$792$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {4}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$1872$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {5}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$2152$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {6}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$25$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {7}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$441$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {8}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$615$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {9}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$2993$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {10}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$2329$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\def \s {11}
\node[draw, circle] at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {$2031$};
\draw[<-, >=latex] ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:\radius) 
   arc ({360/\n * (\s - 1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I use a foreach and still automatically place the text inside the circles?

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution just for saving more keystrokes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\degrees[11]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[radius=16pt,arrows=->,nodesep=2pt,arrowinset=0](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \foreach \l [count=\i from 0] in {456,1562,792,1872,2152,25,441,615,2993,2329,2031} 
        {\Cnodeput(!4 \i\space PtoCrel){A\i}{\l}}
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {0,...,10}
    {
        \ifnum\i=10
            \ncarc{A0}{A10}
        \else
            \ncarc{A\j}{A\i}
        \fi
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Using f(x) = x*x + 8 (mod 3127)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-calculate}
\makeatletter
\def\f#1{\pst@mod{\pscalculate{(#1+2)**2+8}}{3127}\x\x}
\degrees[11]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[radius=16pt,arrows=->,nodesep=2pt,arrowinset=0](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,10}{\Cnodeput(!4 \i\space PtoCrel){A\i}{\f{\i}}}
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {0,...,10}
    {
        \ifnum\i=10
            \ncarc{A0}{A10}
        \else
            \ncarc{A\j}{A\i}
        \fi
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]